# All subdomains to www with exceptions

Tags: regex

I have a regex which is bothering me really!

What I want, is all subdomains except `www.domain.com` goes to `www.domain.com`
This actually works, but `w.domain.com` doesn't match. Actually, if the subdomain contains the character "w" it fails.

This is how it looks:

```
[^www]+\.domain.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[^www]+` is identivcal to `[^w]+` and in effect translates to "one or more characters except for `w`".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

brackets, `[]`, denote a character class. Using `^` in a character class means you're negating it. `[^www]` actually means any character *except* `w` is going to be matched.

Comment: Thanks, makes more sense now... But what would I do, if I wanted to only match on negated "www" ?

Comment: You want all subdomains except www.domain.com to be matched?

Comment: In a mod-rewrite maybe explicitly targeting the www subdomain first, and then add a "catch-all" rule for the rest would work?

Answer (score 1):

```
.*(?<!www).domain.com
```

Will match all subdomains EXCEPT `www.domain.com`

Check here http://regexr.com?30od1

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old - but to avoid a duplicate post -- how would you do the opposite?

allow www (optionally) but exclude all subdomains?

ALLOWED
www.domain.com
domain.com

NOT ALLOWED
spider.domain.com
me.domain.com